# Is lossless storage of cryo liquids practically possible due to pressure?

Tags: pressure, phase-transition, cryogenics

All cryogenic liquid storage tanks I've seen in labs are equipped with pressure relief valves, which will eventually vent all of the liquid when the tank is stored at room temperature.

I am wondering what the limits are for lossless storage of cryo liquids – i.e., liquids that boil at the surrounding air temperature.

So suppose we put a liquid in a pressure vessel at 1 atmosphere (atm) of pressure and temperature T<sub>0</sub>.  At 1 atm the liquid boils at T<sub>B</sub> > T<sub>0</sub>.  We want to store the liquid at some ambient T<sub>A</sub> > T<sub>B</sub>.

My understanding is that there is some pressure >> 1 atm at which the chemical will stay liquid at T<sub>A</sub>, which would mean it can be stored without venting.  If the container can survive that pressure then storage will be lossless.  What is the formula for that pressure?  E.g., is it roughly a function of the expansion ratio of the chemical?  Or does it also strongly depend on the difference T<sub>A</sub> - T<sub>B</sub>?

(It looks like typical small pressure tanks are rated to 250 atm, which is, for example, adequate for lossless storage of various liquefied hydrocarbons like propane and methane.  OTOH, I'm not aware of any static system that can store liquids like O<sub>2</sub> without loss at STP.)

Comment: Usually, you'll have a gas above its critical temperature which may behave like a liquid due to the extremely high pressure. But you'll typically be way above the inversion temperature, so if there is a leak, the escaping gas heats up and may then ignite.

Comment: Look up the arrangements made for compressed natural gas (which is transported in super-panamax tankers). Not actually a cryo-liquid, but an alternative to changing temperature. That is probably not practical for most of the usual cryo-liquids for engineering reasons, but it is nominally there.

Comment: @CountIblis: So is the answer that *if the cryo liquid isn't allowed to vent, but were held under increasing T&P to avoid loss, then what we'd get out of the tank would no longer be a liquid (not would it be cold)*?

Comment: Note that all the "exploding hot-water heater" videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbreKn4PoAc  can be classified as the failure of a sealed cryogenic liquid (water) container